# Batch numeric comparison with if statement

Tags: batch-file, if-statement, numeric

I have searched for the correct syntax when using if statement with a GTR/LSS numerical comparison operands.

My code looks something like this:

```
@echo off
cmd /c

SETLOCAL ENABLEEXPENSIONS
X: ...

IF myVal LSS 0 (
   ECHO Error!
   GOTO X
) ELSE IF myVal GTR 9 (
   ECHO Error!
   GOTO X
)
...
SETLOCAL DISABLEEXPENSIONS
```

Problem is no matter what I input in myVal the error part is  always displayed and I'm stuck in an endless loop.

Is there a problem with my syntax?
Is it a Windows problem maybe?

Comment: Use: `IF %myVal% LSS 0`.  `myVal` is _the name_ of the variable. `%myVal%` is _the value_ of the variable (standard expansion). If the value of the variable change inside parentheses, you need to use `!myVal!` (delayed expansion)

Comment: Tried using %myVal% at the beginning, but didn't work. Droped the % when realized the first condition worked (but the second oddly did not).

Comment: Of course, in order for this to work the `myVal` variable must _not_ be empty...

Comment: also in one line, `if not %myVal% GTR 0 if not %myVal% LSS 9 (…` and `EXPENSIONS`? by default they are enabled since vista, but `extensions`

Comment: `IF %myVal% GEQ 0 IF %myVal% LEQ 9 GOTO OK` and below `ECHO Error! & GOTO X`

Comment: The code in your question is not a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Thanks @Aacini. Your answer worked for me.